# Changed my PATH to have /usr/local/bin ahead of /usr/bin and now pip isn't found

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, python, path

I was following [this guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/osx/) to get Python 3 setup, which recommended changing the PATH variable such that "# If you still see 2.7 ensure in PATH /usr/local/bin/ takes pecedence over /usr/bin/". I put the following in my .profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

This sets my PATH to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

This fixed my `python --version` issue, but now when I type `pip --version` I get

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

in my terminal.

Can anyone please help?!

PS: I'm running Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: The default PATH of newer macOS systems already is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`(check /etc/paths! and compare it with your current PATH: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...` ). So `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` in your bash profile is not required!

Answer (score 1):

Ok... so after a bit more digging I think I found the answer to my own question. While running `pip --version` doesn't work, running `pip3 --version` gives me `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`.

What I think is happening is that pip is located in the same location as python2 that comes with the Mac OS, while pip3 sits in the homebrew location.